# Change php artisan make:controller resource layout

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

When we use

```
php artisan make:controller --resource
```

a controller with basic functions is created.

I want to change this code to add more functions that all controllers will use.

How to change the default resource code?

Comment: So you want to make something like **Laravel generators** : https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended. You can try to take a look at this package, it will help you get started

Comment: @teeyo thank's, I read and didn't found a way to create a custom "controller_default_code.php", have you done that with Laravel Generators?

Comment: I think you need to use Laravel command console, to create your won commands that will generate the code snippets you want : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to @teeyo I was able to make a new search and found this:

https://blog.vigilantmedia.com/2015/08/07/how-to-customize-controllers-generated-by-artisan-in-laravel/